Null extracted folder for artifact: ResolvedArtifact(componentIdentifier=androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0
I build Native SDK for android. To build SDK for react native (for the same product), I used bridging method.
I added native SDKs of Android and iOS in the React native and build an SDK for the react native.
I published this SDK to NPM, it is working fine form me and for many of my clients.
One of my client is facing issue.
Client's project is working fine without importing mine SDK.
But when client is adding my React native SDK in his React native' project's package.json, he is facing an error, error is:

Null extracted folder for artifact: ResolvedArtifact(componentIdentifier=androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0, variantName=null, artifactFile=/Users/apple/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.activity/activity/1.8.0/4266e2118d565daa20212d1726e11f41e1a4d0ca/activity-1.8.0.aar, extractedFolder=null, dependencyType=ANDROID, isWrappedModule=false, buildMapping={current_build=/Users/apple/Desktop/cleanedup_code/Digi_App/android}, mavenCoordinatesCache=com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.depe

Dependencies in client's package.json:
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.16.1", "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.10.0", "@react-native-community/cli": "^9.0.0", "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "^8.0.5", "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.4.7", "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2", "@react-native-ml-kit/text-recognition": "^1.2.1", "@regulaforensics/react-native-face-api": "^3.2.2", "@woonivers/react-native-document-scanner": "^2.1.1", "axios": "^0.21.1", "fuse.js": "^6.6.2", "js-base64": "^3.7.2", "prettier": "^2.7.1", "react": "^16.9.0", "react-hook-form": "^7.6.0", "react-native": "^0.63.4", "react-native-biometrics": "^2.1.4", "react-native-calendars": "^1.1267.0", "react-native-camera": "^3.43.6", "react-native-credit-card-input": "^0.4.1", "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2", "react-native-elements": "^3.4.0", "react-native-fetch-api": "^2.0.0", "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.9.0", "react-native-image-base64": "^0.1.4", "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.33.1", "react-native-image-picker": "^3.0.1", "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^2.0.0", "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.16.1", "react-native-mlkit-ocr": "^0.2.5", "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6", "react-native-modal-selector": "^2.0.3", "react-native-onboarding-swiper": "^1.2.0", "react-native-otp-textinput": "0.0.7", "react-native-permissions": "^2.2.2", "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0", "react-native-progress-circle": "^2.1.0", "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.4", "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.1.1", "react-native-reanimated": "1.13.2", "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2", "react-native-router-flux": "4.2.0", "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1", "react-native-tab-button": "^0.2.0", "react-native-touch-id": "^4.4.1", "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3", "react-redux": "^7.2.2", "redux": "^4.0.5", "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8", "redux-logger": "^3.0.6", "redux-promise": "^0.6.0", "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0", "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.13", "toggle-switch-react-native": "^3.3.0"
**
At client end we tried multiple solutions:**
We changed the compile and target SDK versions to 34.
We asked the client to add
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0")
this in android app level build.gradle file.
We asked him to try this too in the app level build.gradle:
implementation ('com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0') { exclude group: 'androidx.activity', module: 'activity' }
We asked client the remove android.enableJetifier=true this line from gradle.properties.
We asked client to increase memory size by using:
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m this and by increasing more memory size.
I followed these answers too:
StackOverFlow issue
StackOverFlow issue
Nothing is working.
Client is facing the same issue.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
